# Package Issues from expo SDK 42 to SDK 44

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native, npm, expo

I just tried to upgrade my expo app from SDK version 42 to version 44.  I did the following commands:

```
npm i -g expo-cli
expo upgrade
```

When I try to run npm install or npm add expo i get this:

```
The expo package was found in your package.json but we couldn't resolve the Expo SDK version. Run npm install and then try this command again.

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: expo-standard-web-crypto@1.2.0
npm ERR! Found: expo-random@12.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/expo-random
npm ERR!   expo-random@"~12.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional expo-random@"12.1.0" from expo-standard-web-crypto@1.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/expo-standard-web-crypto
npm ERR!   expo-standard-web-crypto@"^1.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: expo-random@12.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/expo-random
npm ERR!   peerOptional expo-random@"12.1.0" from expo-standard-web-crypto@1.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/expo-standard-web-crypto
npm ERR!     expo-standard-web-crypto@"^1.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I've never updated expo before and am unfamiliar with working with dependencies and package.jsons

here is my package.json as well:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "update-deps": "npm install -g npm && npm install -g expo-cli && npm install",
    "build-ios": "expo bi --release-channel beta -t archive",
    "build-android": "expo ba --release-channel beta -t app-bundle"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.1.12",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "5.0.11",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.6",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.9",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "create-react-class": "^15.7.0",
    "expo": "^44.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.4.6",
    "expo-constants": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-file-system": "~13.1.4",
    "expo-font": "~10.0.4",
    "expo-linking": "~3.0.0",
    "expo-mail-composer": "~11.1.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.14.0",
    "expo-print": "~11.1.0",
    "expo-sharing": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.14.1",
    "expo-sqlite": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-standard-web-crypto": "^1.1.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~10.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "native-base": "^2.13.15",
    "pdf-lib": "^1.16.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^5.6.1",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.10.0",
    "react-native-modal-picker": "^0.0.16",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-simple-time-picker": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "utf8": "^3.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "expo-random": "~12.1.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.11.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "~17.0.9",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.64.12",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.29.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.29.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.11.0",
    "jest-expo": "^44.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

This is in a react-native app and I was previously using version 42.  NPM add expo is what is suggested however I get the same error as above.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix might be to delete the `node-modules` folder and run again `npm i` or `yarn`. That should correct the peer-dependencies error.